# Can't focus on textarea with my css style

Tags: html, css

I want to use this [css style](http://codepen.io/jcoulterdesign/pen/GgGrQO) to reply to messages from my asp.net project, but on this example the textarea wont be focused when I click on it with the mouse, also I tried adding a button but the same thing the wont be clicked. Is there a way to change this css style to make the textarea and the button focusable ?
 here is my asp.net page code :

```
@{
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <input id="reclamation_@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ElementAt(i).id)" type="checkbox">
            <label for="reclamation_@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ElementAt(i).id)" href="#move">
                <div class="container_ui__item">
                    <div class="face">
                        <img src=@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ElementAt(i).sender.image) width="70" height="70" />
                        <div class="color_bar one">
                            <p>Now Reading</p>
                            <span>Read</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h2>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ElementAt(i).sender.name)
                    </h2>
                    <div class="dot @(Model.ElementAt(i).sender.state())"></div>
                    <h3>Raison : @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ElementAt(i).title)</h3>
                    <h4>Objet : @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ElementAt(i).object)</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="container_ui__expand" id="close">
                    <div class="heading">
                        <div class="heading_head"></div>
                        <label for="message-1">
                            x
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="body">
                        <div class="user">
                            <div class="face">
                                <img src=@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ElementAt(i).sender.image) >
                            </div>
                            <div class="details">
                                <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ElementAt(i).sender.name)</h2>
                                <h3>Objet : @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ElementAt(i).object)</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <p><b>Content : </b><br>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ElementAt(i).content)</p>
                            <span>Reply:</span>
                            <input type="submit" value="reply"/>
                            <textarea></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </label>
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add for `textarea` - `pointer-events:auto;`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waMPyY